# how to get the value of slider in another page with a button click in xamarin crossplatform

Tags: c#

I am new in Xamarin and I want to go to another screen from one screen. Here i have Two sliders, 2 labels and a button. I want to open another screen after clicking on that button and I should display the values of two sliders in another xaml page.. like slider1 = 2.5 slider2=4. How can i do this?

my cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage

{

    public MainPage()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

  private void MainSlider1_OnValueChanged(object o, ValueChangedEventArgs e)

    {

        Double slider1 = MainSlider1.Value + 1;

        MainLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(slider1);

    }

 private void MainSlider2_OnValueChanged(object o, ValueChangedEventArgs e)

    {

        Double slider2 = MainSlider2.Value + 1;

        MainLabel2.Text = Convert.ToString(slider2);

    }

    private async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object o, EventArgs e)

    {

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters by having a class as below:

```
private async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object o, EventArgs e)
{  
    var yourClass = new YourClass {
      Slider1Text = MainLabel1.Text,
      Slider2Text = MainLabel2.Text
    };

    await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page1(yourClass));
}
```

For this we have to change in the Constructor method of Page1:

```
public Page1(YourClass yourClass)
{

}
```

And you can use the data from YourClass as required.

Comment: i want to do it in blankxamlApp(xamarin.forms.portable)